# throwing error can't find module 'webpage' in phantomjs lambda

Tags: lambda, phantomjs, aws-lambda

I have been trying to run my phantomjs awslambda for taking screenshots of some urls for some official usage. It is giving an error showing that it can't find variable module in the lambda.I was running phantomjs code in the local windows machine so far.I packaged my code along with phantomjs linux binary.Any help would be appreciated.
 this is how i have written my code.

```
exports.myHandler = function(event, context) {
    var url = "http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41711963/edit";
    var Id = "c4f3b48d-469a-448a-8a8e-c5a09d1e79fd";
//  var EncodedUri = "NB2HI4B2F4XXO53XFZZWKY3VOJUXI6LGN5RXK4ZOMNXW2L3CNFSC6NZXGIYTC===";


    var pattern = /mp[3-4]$/;
    if(pattern.test(url) == true){
        console.log("Matched:");
        var base64 = "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";
        console.log(base64);
    }
    else{
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.viewportSize = {
              width: 15,
              height: 45
            };
    page.zoomFactor = 0.15;
    page.open(url);
    console.log("waiting for page to load...")
    page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
      setTimeout(function(){
          console.log('Status: ' + status);
          var render =  renderPageThumbNail(page);
      },10000)
    }

    var renderPageThumbNail = function(page){
        console.log("It will render the thumbnail of the url");
        var base64 = page.renderBase64('png');
//      var path = 'D:/MyProjectsWorkSpace/ScreenShots/output.txt';
        console.log(base64);
        phantom.exit();
    }
    }
}
```

It is breaking at the line  var page = require('webpage').create();

Comment: Why `node.js` tag? Do you run this script as a node.js script or against a PhantomJS binary?

Comment: @Vaviloff phatomjs binary